# ExternalProject Error: file attempted to create a directory into a source directory

Tags: cmake

I'm writing CMake scripts for my project and I'm trying to call another compiler for subset of files, located under subdirectory of the project source tree.

I've found that I can do it using `ExternalProject_Add` command.

Here is the part of my code

Root CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES ON)
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD ON)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt

```
... 

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(subproject_name
        PREFIX subproject
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/subproject
        DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
        # UPDATE_COMMAND ""
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/custom.toolchain.cmake
        
)
```

However, I'm getting following errors:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:1695 (file):
  file attempted to create a directory:
  /home/user/project/src/subproject into a source directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:3156 (_ep_set_directories)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:93 (ExternalProject_Add)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I've read manual on `ExternalProject_Add` several times. It says clearly:

> SOURCE_DIR ...
>
> If no download method is specified, this must point to an existing directory where the external project has already been unpacked or cloned/checked out.

> DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ...
> Overrides the command used for the download step (generator expressions are supported). If this option is specified, all other download options will be ignored. Providing an empty string for  effectively disables the download step.

So, to my mind, CMake should take sources in the subdirectory and create build system under build subdirectory.

However, it tries to create directory `src/subproject` that already exists.

I've also tried removing `PREFIX` argument, but have got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might try removing the `PREFIX subproject` argument.

Comment: Tried - doesn't help

Comment: It seems that current implementation of `ExternalProject_Add` conflicts with `CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD` option. See that bugreport: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18811.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, if you wish, you could convert your comment to answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @wl2776: Done. I have also edit the title of your question for reflect the error message you got. That way it will help others with the similar error to find your question easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that current implementation of `ExternalProject_Add` conflicts with `CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD` option. You need to avoid this option when `SOURCE_DIR` parameter for `ExternalProject_Add` points **inside** your **source tree**.

See that bugreport: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18811.

Comment: Nice "hack" :) You may prepare your own answer with this approach, if you wish.

Comment: I've changed my script to `set(CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES OFF)` `ExternalProject_Add(...)` `set(CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES ON)`
In-source builds are still forbidden